# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Overflows rather than adjusts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar I am creating that has a bunch of menus and submenus. The menus are trailing off the point of viewing and allowing my page to scroll which is not my desired result. I would like for it to flip from right menu to left if there is not enough room for it.

For my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5d3zhs6m/) I have a quick demo that fairly accurately represents my real navbar. To replicate my issue position the webpage depending on your resolution so that the navbar is forced off the side of the page. Click on the interactive tab and on the right column (ignore the styling) click stuff system and go into those submenus. They will trail off the page unviewable unless you scroll which is not what I want.

I have tried using `right:0;left:auto;` as well as positions for the css as I have found in other discussions but that did not help. I also have tried to use a JQuery menu that worked for the most part but didn't do everything I needed so that is not an option currently. How can I get it to be responsive and realize that it cannot overflow off the page?

UPDATE: I have created a bounty as I need an answer for this. I have modified the question slightly.

Comment: are u looking for this? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you have to use `JavaScript` to make the menu dynamically change its style based on the *viewport*.

Luckely for all of us, there are some great guys on the web who create these things for existing frameworks. So others don't have to invent an existing wheel. Take a look at the link below. This is exaclty what you are looking for (atleast, as far as I can see in your question).

http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html#

It is fully compatible with bootstrap 3.

Comment: I tried SmartMenus but could not get a two column menu like I show in the fiddle. I tried the `Mega-Menu` since it allows all HTML but it did not work for me.

Comment: Hm, It should work the way your want, as it is bootstrap compatible.

Comment: I am giving your answer another shot and have gotten closer to my desired result. However I tried the answer found here [link](https://www.smartmenus.org/forums/topic/sub-menu-with-two-columns/) and it appears I have two columns. But how do I get objects in the right column?

Comment: Ive no idea what you mean, but I guess you have to put your HTML inside the `<ul class="columns-2"> ...`

Comment: I made a fiddle that hopefully you could provide some guidance to. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3rvhud99/)

Comment: Sorry, ive no idea how to do it based on your fiddle.

Comment: This won the bounty because it is the only solution that works according to keeping the contents on the screen dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary fix (Not dynamic)

Use the following CSS rules

```
ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-inverse {
    position: absolute;
    left:-58% 
    /* Overriding value from 100% defined in ".dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu"  */

    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
```

For a responsive solution, basically calculate the width of each menu and add them up.

Then subtract the value from the screenwidth and then add the above class to the subject.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/5d3zhs6m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this css rule in the media queries (at widths that have the problem). It should sort it out to what i believe you want

```
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
   top: 0;
   left: -92%;
   margin-top: -6px;
   margin-right: -1px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
   border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5d3zhs6m/3/)

Comment: No, what he means is that the menu goes out of viewport when he has alot of submenu's in it. Atleast, thats what I get out of the question ;)

Comment: @Red my option fixes that, on mobile they cascade into the menu inline.

Comment: When I open the fiddle, and go to the submenu's, its still out of the viewport. Perhaps your screen is too small to see this issue, because bootstrap switch to mobile view?

Comment: @Red https://i.imgur.com/5zJHHzf.png - you dont see that when hovering over the dropdown in the dropdown?  the inline text appears

Comment: This is what he mean, you have to mobile view. I see the desktop view https://imgur.com/tZ5EZSL

Comment: that would be the mobile view @Deckerz

Comment: @SgtOVERKILL see edit. i misunderstood what you want. Only caveat is it needs to be in media queries for the affected widths.

Comment: Well, as it is now it isnt really responsive, as there might be even more submenus.

Comment: @Red anything that goes more than 3-4 submenus deep have other problems than responsiveness. I think this is suffice for what he is asking. It can be easily adapted for `nth-instance` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-toggle:hover + .dropdown-menu{
    display: block ;
  }
```